Nuxt 3 @sidebase/nuxt-auth How change session data?
I have api endpoint user/profile
return json data
{ "data": { "first_name": "Rafael", "last_name": "Rafael", "email": "rafael@mail.com", "phone": "+7111111111" }, "message": "Completed successfully", "status": true }

when authorizing all this data is saved in the session I only need the data field
nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    authSecret: '12345678',
  },
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt', '@sidebase/nuxt-auth'],

  auth: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8001/api/v1/en/',
    provider: {
      type: 'local',
      token: {
        signInResponseTokenPointer: '/data/token',
        type: '',
        cookieName: 'auth.token',
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        maxAgeInSeconds: 1800,
        sameSiteAttribute: 'lax',
        cookieDomain: 'localhost',
        secureCookieAttribute: false,
        httpOnlyCookieAttribute: false,
      },
      endpoints: {
        signIn: { path: 'login', method: 'post' },
        signOut: { path: 'logout', method: 'post' },
        signUp: { path: 'register', method: 'post' },
        getSession: { path: 'user/profile', method: 'get' },
      },
    },
    sessionRefresh: {
      enablePeriodically: false,
      enableOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },


What need write here  server/api/auth/[...].ts if i use  provider type local?

Hi, i'm having similar issues and I wanted to know how do you parse your response to json. Because my response is in xml. I wanted to add a header like options.headers.Accept = 'application/json'; but I couldn't do it...

nuxt.config.ts need add this

session: { dataResponsePointer: '/data' },

export default defineNuxtConfig({   
 modules: ['@pinia/nuxt', '@sidebase/nuxt-auth'],    
  auth: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8001/api/v1/en/',
    provider: {
      type: 'local',
      token: {
        signInResponseTokenPointer: '/data/token',
        type: '',
        cookieName: 'auth.token',
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        maxAgeInSeconds: 1800,
        sameSiteAttribute: 'lax',
        cookieDomain: 'localhost',
        secureCookieAttribute: false,
        httpOnlyCookieAttribute: false,
      },
      session: { dataResponsePointer: '/data' },
      endpoints: {
        signIn: { path: 'login', method: 'post' },
        signOut: { path: 'logout', method: 'post' },
        signUp: { path: 'register', method: 'post' },
        getSession: { path: 'user/profile', method: 'get' },
      },
    },
    sessionRefresh: {
      enablePeriodically: false,
      enableOnWindowFocus: false,
    },   
},

